# C/C++ FastCGI Developers toolkit example program (not working?)

Tags: c++, c, linux, apache, fastcgi

I am using the [fastcgi C/C++ toolkit](http://www.fastcgi.com/drupal/node/5), to develop a test fastcgi app. 
I built (and am now testing) [this example](http://www.fastcgi.com/devkit/examples/echo-cpp.cpp) provided by the toolkit.

I have loaded Apache mod_fcgid and successfully restarted the apache2 daemon. However, when I try to access the fastcgi resource, it is returning a blank page.

***Note:*** I made the following changes to the example code (as it didn't work with the default socket fd value of 0):

```
int sock_fd = FCGX_OpenSocket(":5000", 1);
FCGX_InitRequest(&request, sock_fd, 0);
```

My /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/fcgid.conf file looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
     AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
     SocketPath /var/lib/apache2/fcgid/sock
     IPCConnectTimeout 10
     IPCCommTimeout 20
     OutputBufferSize 0
     MaxRequestsPerProcess 500
</IfModule>
```

My /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/fcgid.load file looks like this:

```
LoadModule fcgid_module /my/path/here/libs/mod_fcgid.so
```

I then accessed the 'resource' in a browser using the following url:

http://127.0.0.1:5000

What am I doing wrong? (assuming that someone has actually managed to get the example cited above, to work)

I am developing/testing on Linux Ubuntu 10.x

Comment: Have you looked at your logs (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/logs.html) to see if any hints are in there?

Comment: @PDI: There are no messages relating to fastcgi (or fcgid for that matter), in the apache log file

Comment: This is a longshot but what I read about fastcgi is that the OpenSocket call will create a file but that file will need the correct permissions to allow the webserver to connect.  I think it needs both read and write for the user the webserver is running under.

Answer (score 0):

i don't use apache for while, but i think your url is bad
i assume your apache run on port 80 and your echo.fcgi is at root of apache folder

for information, i use nginx for serve fcgi application

```
http://localhost/echo.fcgi
```

Answer (score 0):

Run apachctl -D to verify your have mod_fcgid running.  I believe no output (i.e a white page) occurs when your process crashes.

You will need to compile your program with debugging (-O0 -ggdb), redeploy, and restart Apache.

Change your Apache config to only spawn one process.  This will allow you to attach gdb to your FCGI application and debug it.

Let me know if you need further assistance.

Comment: Oh, as PDI suggests, a permission problem could very well be possible. Make sure Apache has permission to execute your FCGI binary.